# Mat-card-content not appearing properly

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I have the following angular html code,

```
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <mat-card style="height:400px; display: grid; margin:7px 0px 7px 0px !important;">
      <mat-card-header>
          Number of Rides for last week days
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content style="padding-bottom: 0px">
        <ngx-charts-bar-vertical 
          [scheme]="barChartScheme" 
          [results]="data" 
          [gradient]="gradient" 
          [xAxis]="showXAxis" 
          [yAxis]="showYAxis"
          [legend]="showLegend" 
          [legendTitle]="title" 
          [animations]="true" 
          [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" 
          [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
          [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" 
          [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" 
          (select)="onSelect($event)">
        </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap for the responsive model,

But the `mat-card-content` which is a `ngx-chart` here, is not taking the remaining part of the `mat-card` space for rendering, but it get shrinked to a single line as follows,

[image]

The `mat-card-header` is displaying correctly. I have taken it off from the screenshot.

Please help me, what is wrong here.

Comment: Please create a stackblitz.com project replicating the issue.

Comment: Are you trying something like this. -----> https://ngx-chart-bar-vertical.stackblitz.io

Comment: @UnluckyAj, yeah I am trying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Working Fine for me:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chart-bar-vertical)

style.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

body {
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin:20px
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <mat-card style="height:400px; display: grid; margin:7px 0px 7px 0px !important;">
            <mat-card-header>
                Number of Rides for last week days
            </mat-card-header> 
            <mat-card-content style="padding-bottom: 0px">
                <ngx-charts-bar-vertical [view]="view" [scheme] ="colorScheme" [results]="single" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis"
                 [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
                 [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" (select)="onSelect($event)">
                </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  single: any[];
  multi: any[];

  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Country';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Population';

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { single })
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxChartsModule} from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,BrowserAnimationsModule, MatCardModule, FormsModule,NgxChartsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
}) 
export class AppModule { }
```